# How do I create a JAR with m2e (m2eclipse)?

Tags: java, maven, jar, m2eclipse

I'm new to Maven and m2e.  It frustrates me that I have to ask this question, but the sparse m2e documentation and Google are failing me.

How do get m2e to build a JAR?  I understand that this should happen during the maven package phase, but m2e doesn't seem to do this as part of the build process and I can't find a way to explicitly execute the package phase in Eclipse (nor any other phases that aren't part of the default build).

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as you have your POM.xml file with the following parameters:

```
<modelVersion>[a model number eg 4.0.0]</modelVersion>
<groupId>[a group id eg com.myapp]</groupId>
<artifactId>[a unique artifact id within your packages eg myapp]</artifactId>
<version>[the version number eg 1.0-SNAPSHOT]</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>[the name eg myapp]</name>
```

then you just need to run maven build with the goals `clean install` to create a jar file from your project. You can run maven build by right clinking on the project and going to run > maven build ...

The jar will be created in [project dir]/target

Comment: Fantastic! The key detail I was missing was the pointer the the Maven options under "Run As".  I couldn't find a way to execute an arbitrary Maven phase to save my life...

m2e desperately needs a decent tutorial...

Comment: @HolySamosa: remember that you can still go to the 'POM directory' and run your maven commands via command line (mvn clean install). It's sometimes easier than using the 'Run as' configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Although "Run As maven install" would do the trick, it can be good 
to know that m2e will perform the equivalent of the package phase when doing "Export... Jar/War/EAR file".  It seems to understand the plugin configurations too, at least a little bit, and at least for EARs...

As it will resolve artifacts using projects and the m2 repository,
it will also work for "unrelated" modules, as the dependency that resolves to a project is good enough for eclipse to package.
(That is, you don't have to install the unrelated dependency separately, it will be built automatically from the eclipse project.)

I'm not sure I would deploy anything it builds though :-)