# encrypt maven passwords within eclipse using m2e

Tags: maven, maven-2, m2eclipse, m2e

There is a really nice guide on the maven site about how to encrypt passwords that get stored within POM files located at http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html

Can these operations be done within eclipse using the m2e plugin, or must I have my guys download maven before they can create encrypted passwords and master passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m2e comes with an embedded maven installation. From Eclipse (using Run configurations) you can run arbitrary maven commands, including the ones related to password encryption.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839238/how-do-i-create-a-jar-with-m2e-m2eclipse) related SO question